# When React requests to Django API, net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR is occured

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

Stack : AWS Lightsail, React, DRF, Django, Gunicorn, NGINX

I created certificate using Let's Encrypt.

※ I followed this site : 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

So, I can access https://mydomain without error.

But when React calls Django API, net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR is occured.

I think there's something I need to set up in DRF, Django.

Cause no error logged in syslog and /var/log/nginx/error.log.

I googled but couldn't find what I wanted.

Can I ask for advice? Thank you.

---

**EDIT** : Below is the NGINX's conf file.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name mydomain;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        root /react_project_path/build;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name mydomain;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass https://unix:/django_project_path/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /django_project_path/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /django_project_path/media/;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT** : netstat result.

[image: netstat]

---

**EDIT** : Now I checking my logs.

I just added a line of code.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name mydomain;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ...
```

And below is the NGINX's error.log. (I edited path, token, session here for private.)

```
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: accept on 0.0.0.0:443, ready: 0
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: posix_memalign: 0000556469DEEA20:512 @16
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 accept: 218.235.196.18:8093 fd:3
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 event timer add: 3: 60000:23210254
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 reusable connection: 1
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 epoll add event: fd:3 op:1 ev:80002001
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http check ssl handshake
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http recv(): 1
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 https ssl handshake: 0x16
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 tcp_nodelay
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL ALPN supported by client: h2
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL ALPN supported by client: http/1.1
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL ALPN selected: http/1.1
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL_get_error: 2
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 reusable connection: 0
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL handshake handler: 0
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL: TLSv1.2, cipher: "ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH Au=RSA Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL reused session
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 reusable connection: 1
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http wait request handler
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 malloc: 0000556469DF3390:1024
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL_read: -1
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL_get_error: 2
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 free: 0000556469DF3390
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http wait request handler
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 malloc: 0000556469DF3390:1024
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL_read: 813
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL_read: -1
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL_get_error: 2
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 reusable connection: 0
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 posix_memalign: 0000556469E3DC90:4096 @16
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http process request line
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http request line: "GET /character/ironclad HTTP/1.1"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http uri: "/character/ironclad"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http args: ""
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http exten: ""
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 posix_memalign: 0000556469EAAA50:4096 @16
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http process request header line
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "Host: mydomain"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "Connection: keep-alive"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "Sec-Fetch-User: ?1"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "Sec-Fetch-Dest: document"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "Referer: https://mydomain/"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "Accept-Language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "Cookie: csrftoken=some_data; sessionid=some_data"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "If-None-Match: W/"5f577837-8e2""
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header: "If-Modified-Since: Tue, 08 Sep 2020 12:25:27 GMT"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http header done
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 event timer del: 3: 23210254
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 generic phase: 0
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 rewrite phase: 1
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 test location: "/"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 using configuration "/"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 rewrite phase: 3
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 post rewrite phase: 4
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 generic phase: 5
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 generic phase: 6
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 generic phase: 7
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 access phase: 8
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 access phase: 9
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 access phase: 10
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 post access phase: 11
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 generic phase: 12
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 try files handler
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http script var: "/character/ironclad"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 trying to use file: "/character/ironclad" "/react_project_path/build/character/ironclad"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http script var: "/character/ironclad"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 trying to use dir: "/character/ironclad" "/react_project_path/build/character/ironclad"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 trying to use file: "/index.html" "/react_project_path/build/index.html"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 internal redirect: "/index.html?"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 rewrite phase: 1
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 test location: "/"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 using configuration "/"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 rewrite phase: 3
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 post rewrite phase: 4
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 generic phase: 5
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 generic phase: 6
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 generic phase: 7
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 access phase: 8
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 access phase: 9
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 access phase: 10
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 post access phase: 11
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 generic phase: 12
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 try files handler
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http script var: "/index.html"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 trying to use file: "/index.html" "/react_project_path/build/index.html"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 try file uri: "/index.html"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 generic phase: 13
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 content phase: 14
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 content phase: 15
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 content phase: 16
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 content phase: 17
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 content phase: 18
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http filename: "/react_project_path/build/index.html"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 add cleanup: 0000556469E3EB80
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http static fd: 14
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http set discard body
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http ims:1599567927 lm:1599567927
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http im:"W/"5f577837-8e2"" etag:"5f577837-8e2"
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 xslt filter header
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 write new buf t:1 f:0 0000556469EAAF10, pos 0000556469EAAF10, size: 189 file: 0, size: 0
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:189
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http write filter limit 0
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 posix_memalign: 0000556469EAC6D0:512 @16
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 malloc: 0000556469EB15C0:16384
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL buf copy: 189
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL to write: 189
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 SSL_write: 189
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http write filter 0000000000000000
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http finalize request: 0, "/index.html?" a:1, c:2
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http request count:2 blk:0
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http finalize request: -4, "/index.html?" a:1, c:1
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 set http keepalive handler
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http close request
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 http log handler
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 run cleanup: 0000556469E3EB80
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 file cleanup: fd:14
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 free: 0000556469E3DC90, unused: 0
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 free: 0000556469EAAA50, unused: 2427
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 free: 0000556469DF3390
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 hc free: 0000000000000000
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 free: 0000556469EB15C0
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 reusable connection: 1
2020/09/09 15:46:29 [debug] 3322#3322: *13 event timer add: 3: 65000:23215262
```

At this point,

I think traffic does not reach Django or even GUnicorn and seems to be blocked by SSL errors in NGINX.

But I still don't think I have enough information to find the cause of the error.

Please give me an advice, thank you.

Comment: I believe you are supposed to add an SSL certificate

Comment: @dsfx3d What is add? You mean add certificate's path at NGINX's conf?

Comment: Have you added the certificates in your project apache conf file?

Comment: @ShahidTariq Apache? But I using NGINX. Both of them are web server. So I uninstalled unnecessary Apache. It still need?

Comment: Can you check your conf file on the server and check if it includes the path to your created certificates

Comment: @ShahidTariq Yes, I checked my conf and it includes.

Comment: check if your server is listening to port 443

Comment: @ShahidTariq Yes, I checked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is really simple, just add 'ssl' after listen 8000.

```
...
server {
    listen 8000 ssl;
    server_name mydomain;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass https://unix:/django_project_path/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /django_project_path/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /django_project_path/media/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you have add ssl for it to work. Whenever I do ```listen 80``` I do not need to add ssl